# Getting an Error while running test-app -coverage command for grails even all test case passed

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 2.1.1 and for code coverage plugin i am using code-coverage1.2.5

I have noticed that my test case pass successful with test-app command but not generating the cobertura report by the command "test-app -coverage --stacktrace"

Below is the error i am getting

```
Flushing results done
    Cobertura: Loaded information on 320 classes.
    Cobertura: Saved information on 320 classes.
    | Error Exception occurred trigger event [TestPhasesEnd]: Could not create a new instance of class [com.sigmainfo.cooptimum.connectplus.priorapproval.PriorApprovalController]! (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
    org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [com.sigmainfo.cooptimum.connectplus.priorapproval.PriorApprovalController]!
        at _Events$_replaceClosureNames_closure5.doCall(_Events.groovy:115)
        at _Events.replaceClosureNames(_Events.groovy:113)
        at _Events$replaceClosureNames.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at _Events.replaceClosureNamesInReports(_Events.groovy:105)
        at _Events$_run_closure3.doCall(_Events.groovy:59)
        at _GrailsEvents_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsEvents_groovy:53)
        at _GrailsEvents_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsEvents_groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:223)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:82)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sigmainfo.cooptimum.connectplus.DealerBaseInfo.findAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), findAll(java.lang.Object), findAll(java.lang.String), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)
        at com.sigmainfo.cooptimum.connectplus.DealerBaseInfo.findAll(DealerBaseInfo.groovy)
        at com.sigmainfo.cooptimum.connectplus.DealerBaseInfo$findAll.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.sigmainfo.cooptimum.connectplus.priorapproval.PriorApprovalController.<init>(PriorApprovalController.groovy:32)
        ... 42 more
    | Error Exception occurred trigger event [TestPhasesEnd]: Could not create a new instance of class [com.sigmainfo.cooptimum.connectplus.priorapproval.PriorApprovalController]!
    Flushing results...
    Flushing results done
    Cobertura: Loaded information on 320 classes.
    Cobertura: Saved information on 320 classes.
```

Below is the code snippet of controller

```
class PriorApprovalController extends FileUploaderController{
    Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.subject
    def baseRecordList = DealerBaseInfo.findAll("from DealerBaseInfo as dealers",[cache: false])
    def dataSource
    def mailSenderService
    def exportService
    def priorApprovalInfo
    def currentuser
    def dealerBaseInfo1
```

I am getting the error at line

```
def baseRecordList = DealerBaseInfo.findAll("from DealerBaseInfo as dealers",[cache: false])
```

Comment: you should consider to give some more information, not just the thread title and some stacktrace...

Comment: please add more details to your question; a snippet of the code causing the error, what do you suspect to be causing the error and what have you tried

Comment: You should at least provide Grails version and full command line that you have invoked.

Comment: def baseRecordList = DealerBaseInfo.findAll("from DealerBaseInfo as dealers",[cache: false])
    def dataSource
    def mailSenderService
    def exportService
    def priorApprovalInfo
    def currentuser
    def dealerBaseInfo1
    def dummyUserList = [
        '11111111',
        '22222222',
        '33333333',
        '44444444'
    ]
    def dummyEmails = [
        'asad.ansari.mail@gmail.com'
    ]
    def index() {

    }

Answer (score 0):

find all u  calling should not be called at class level your domain is not injected u can try with static method in domain and call that method